# complexity of (n^2/2)+(n^2*logn)

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I'm trying to solve exercises about  algorithms complexity and in a case like the one in the title I'm not sure on how to proceed.

I know that I would have to find the fastest growing term and remove the coefficient unless the coefficient includes another term:

for example: (n^2)*logn complexity is O((n^2)*logn) and (n^2)*2 complexity is O(n^2).

What I did was simplifying the function to n^2(1/2+logn), but after that I'm not sure if the complexity would just be O(n^2(1/2+logn)) or if the result is something else.

Comment: `O(1/2 + logn) = O(logn)`

Comment: @Damien so the result would be O(n^2*logn)?

Comment: Yes. `(n^2 logn) / (n^2 / 2)` tends to infinite when `n` tends to infinite

Comment: @Damien thanks! to understand better if I grasped the idea, if I had n^2(1/2+logn+n) the result would be O(n^2*n) and if I had n^2(1/2+logn+n+nlogn) it would be O(n^2*nlogn), is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Damien suggested in the comment, the answer is:
O(1/2 + logn) = O(logn)